# Haskell split lines into list including empty lines

Tags: list, string, haskell

So have this

```
type DocName = FilePath
type Line = (Int,String)
type Document = [Line]

splitLines :: String -> Document
splitLines [] = []
splitLines str = zip [0..(length listStr)] listStr
                                    where 
                                        listStr = [getLine] ++ map snd (splitLines getRest)
                                        getLine = (takeWhile (/='\n') str)
                                        getRest =  (dropWhile (=='\n') (dropWhile (/='\n') str))
```

works ok except i guess i need empty lines as well.

```
splitLines "test\nthis\nstring\n" should be
[(0,"test"),(1,"this"),(2,"string"),(3,"")]
```

Not exactly sure how i could do this. Any ideas?
Do i need to rewrite it with something else?

Should i use a high order function like foldr?
Thanks.

Figured it out finally thanks.

```
splitLines :: String -> Document
splitLines "" = [(0,"")]
splitLines str = zip [0..(length listStr)] listStr
                                    where 
                                        listStr = [getLine] ++ map snd (splitLines getRest)
                                        getLine = takeWhile (/='\n') str
                                        getRest = tail (dropWhile (/='\n') str)
```

Comment: Why do your tuples need to duplicate the index? Is `lines` not what you want?

Comment: cant use lines. have to create our own lines function. How could i use index? Wasn't sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's discarding the empty lines because you're doing `dropWhile (=='\n`)`, removing all linebreaks from the beginning of the string.

To keep the empty lines, you must only drop one linebreak. The easiest way to do that is to use pattern matching:

```
getRest = case (dropWhile (/='\n') str) of
              (_:xs) -> xs
              [] -> []
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you don't get the empty lines as you are trimming the new line character off of the start of the string. It would be a lot easier to see this if `splitLines` was refactored slightly. Since you cannot use `lines` it I would start by creating a simple `split` function (you could also use [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/split)):

```
split :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split a [] = [[]]
split a lst = (\(xs, y:ys) -> [xs] ++ split a ys) $ break (==a) lst
```

With this function, `splitLines` is simple:

```
splitLines :: String -> Document
splitLines [] = []
splitLines str = zip [0..] $ split '\n' str
```

Comment: honestly i don't even think i can use split and break. But i did finally get it. Thanks.